# Adding PPA TimeoutError

Tags: ppa, timeout

This is a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04. I can install appimages and use flatpaks or snaps fine, but I get the same error trying to add any PPA:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:appimagelauncher-team/stable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 364, in <module>
    sys.exit(0 if addaptrepo.main() else 1)
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 347, in main
    shortcut = handler(source, **shortcut_params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/shortcuts.py", line 40, in shortcut_handler
    return handler(shortcut, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 82, in __init__
    if self.lpppa.publish_debug_symbols:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 120, in lpppa
    self._lpppa = self.lpteam.getPPAByName(name=self.ppaname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 107, in lpteam
    self._lpteam = self.lp.people(self.teamname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 98, in lp
    self._lp = login_func("%s.%s" % (self.__module__, self.__class__.__name__),
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 494, in login_anonymously
    return cls(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 230, in __init__
    super(Launchpad, self).__init__(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/resource.py", line 472, in __init__
    self._wadl = self._browser.get_wadl_application(self._root_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 447, in get_wadl_application
    response, content = self._request(url, media_type=wadl_type)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 389, in _request
    response, content = self._request_and_retry(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 359, in _request_and_retry
    response, content = self._connection.request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1725, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 144, in _request
    response, content = super(LaunchpadOAuthAwareHttp, self)._request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 184, in _request
    return super(RestfulHttp, self)._request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1441, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1363, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1153, in connect
    sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

I have updated/upgraded in the terminal and everything is up to date from the software center.

Comment: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474534&page=2

Comment: can you try `ping launchpad.net` and paste output, then `sudo apt install traceroute` and paste output from `traceroute -m 50 launchpad.net`? Might be an issue with your connection to launchpad (since you have a timeout error)

Comment: Thank you, sorry for the long delay. I believe it was something wrong with my connection because things started working the next day with no change on my end.